# WPF ArrangeOverride question

Tags: wpf

It seems that the final width(or height) passed in to ArrangeOverride method is never less than the desired width (or height) returned from the MeasureOverride method.

Is this always true?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can assume that the final size passed in will be *less than or equal to* the desired size, but not always the exact size. Arrange is after it decides the actual dimensions things will be, so it will generally be actual values (as opposed to Measure where +Inf is common)

Comment: To me it looks like the final size passed into ArrangeOverride is based on what I return in MeasureOverride. If I return a bogus value (e.g. height of 10,000), that gets passed to ArrangeOverride, even tough my app. window height is only a few hundered pixels.

Comment: It depends on the container your panel was in - if you're in a ScrollViewer for example, it's going to give you all the room you want.

Comment: As Paul says, the container makes a difference. I experienced the same issue as in the question. Then I replaced the container from StackPanel to Grid, and suddenly ArrangeOverride started to behave as expected.

Comment: @PaulBetts When you say "it's going to give all the room", where is it going to do so ? If I inherit from `Canvas` and override `ArrangeOverride` to implement something like this : `foreach (var child in base.InternalChildren) { child.Arrange(new Point(.., A_SMALLER_SIZE }`, then wouldn't the sizes of my canvas' children be constrained to 'A_SMALLER_SIZE' ?